# "Destroy" Thread in Progressbar

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

again I turn to you for a question that I have been presented.
I have a class that extend the class service and implements the class Runnable for audio playback, I'm working with a progressbar to display the progress of the reproduction of music. In the run method add the code to update the value of the progressbar, up there all right, but when I'm playing a song and jump to another without finishing the previous one, the thread that was created earlier is not destroyed, help me please?

```
public class PlaySongService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, Runnable {

public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
private ProgressBar pbSong;
private final String TAG = "PlaySongService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

public void onCreate() {
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    pbSong = new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(Main.pbSong);
    super.onCreate();

}

....... /* Selected song in listview*/

private void playSong(int position) {
    try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(my_file_selected_in_listview);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            pbSong.get().setProgress(0);
            pbSong.get().setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int currentPosition= 0;
    int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    while (mediaPlayer!=null && currentPosition<total) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition= mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            Log.i(TAG,Thread.currentThread().toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        pbSong.get().setProgress(currentPosition);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try check !isplaying to dismiss progress

Answer (score 0):

Threads are not "destroyed" under normal circumstances, they end when they `return` from the run method. This can be initiated by e.g. a boolean flag or by call to `interrupt()` (outside of the thread) and periodic checking of `Thread.interrupted()` in the thread.